# What is The Scope of Kali Linux?

Tags: linux, debian, kali-linux

What is the scope-of-use of Kali Linux and can it be used slightly as a regular Linux repo? It seems by-and-large to be a pen testing tool which is fine because ultimately, that is why I installed it onto one of my machines. However, this is also my first time using Linux and so I'm also learning the Linux system in general and I've come to realize that some things that are available on "general use" Linux systems may not be available on Kali, such as user accounts. I also read in the Kali Docs that supposedly Kali has not been tested for certain software types and therefore you should avoid installing them so as to not "break" the OS.

This makes me confused on what I can and cannot do with Kali. However, I am a software developer, so I am not *completely lost* as far as commandlines go and other technical jargon. My main purpose for using this OS is indeed to penetration test my own web apps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pretty much any distro (Kali included) can be used as a decent desktop. Even Knoppix or openBSD can make for a desktop if you are up for a challenge.  The point here is that the OS comes with a C compiler and a C library (`gcc` and `glibc` in most cases but `llvm` may be an option) from where you can compile pretty much anything you may want.  Of course, you're limited to open source software since you are compiling it from source.

Hell, you can even compile [*everything* from scratch](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/lfs/).

The exception to the rule that a *BSD/Linux distro can be used as an effective desktop are embedded systems.  Some embedded systems purposely leave the C compiler out, so you cannot compile extra software.

---

All that said, Kali Linux uses Debian repositories, from which you can get everything available on Debian with simple `apt-get` (no need for compilation).  Including several window managers, mail programs, browsers.  Really, much more than you can go through.

Answer (score 4):

Kali Linux is a distribution for experienced Linux users which packs network penetration testing tools. It is designed to be run in a virtual machine with little persistent data.

Kali *can* be used as a general-purpose system, but it isn't designed to, and trying to use it for other purposes frequently leads to frustration. (Source: the endless stream of questions we get on Stack Exchange from people who tried to use Kali for something it wasn't designed for.)

**Kali is for experienced users**. If you aren't familiar with the Linux command line and with networking, use a friendlier distribution such as elementary OS, Linux Mint or Ubuntu.

Although you can upgrade packages on Kali, it isn't designed to be a long-term system with smooth upgrades. **Kali is best run as a throwaway live system in a virtual machine**: just keep a few configuration files in your home directory, or access them from the host. If you feel like upgrading, get a new Kali image. For your main system, run a stable distribution.

If you need additional drivers to support your hardware, you'll have an easier time finding or building them for popular distributions such as Ubuntu and Fedora or RHEL/CentOS than for Kali. Run a general-purpose distribution as your main system and run Kali in a virtual machine.